# MySQL [Error] 1064

Tags: mysql, explain, navicat

I got this MySQL error 1064 when I ran the EXPLAIN on VIEWS table in Navicat and could not figure out where exactly the error from in this brief code:

```
SET @runningbal = 0;
SELECT
cashinflow_v.TxnDate,
cashinflow_v.TxnType,
cashinflow_v.Amount,    
@runningbal := @runningbal + cashinflow_v.Amount as Balance
FROM
cashinflow_v
ORDER BY cashinflow_v.TxnDate
```

The error says:

```
[SQL] EXPLAIN SET @runningbal = 0;
SELECT
cashinflow_v.TxnDate,
cashinflow_v.TxnType,
cashinflow_v.Amount,
@runningbal := @runningbal + cashinflow_v.Amount as Balance
FROM
cashinflow_v
ORDER BY cashinflow_v.TxnDate

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET 
@runningbal = 0;
SELECT
cashinflow_v.TxnDate,
cashinflow_v.TxnType,
cash' at line 1
```

I will appreciate if anyone could help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a code before set?

Comment: No actually. I am using Navicat.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

**from:**

```
EXPLAIN SET @runningbal = 0;
```

**to**

```
 SET @runningbal = 0;
```

Comment: also remove [SQL] if present.

Comment: Actually its running without EXPLAIN. But I am just worried that when I run EXPLAIN to check performance of the query it gives me that message error.

Comment: It is your problem that is why i posted to change it.

Comment: Thanks by the way. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

The [`EXPLAIN` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) expects either a table name or a query of one of these types:

- SELECT
- DELETE
- INSERT
- REPLACE
- UPDATE

It's just not designed to provide information of arbitrary SQL commands (how could it?).

If it's your SQL client the one that's trying to explain the query, you may need to instruct it to handle the code block as script rather than individual statement.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using VIEWS (virtual table) instead of the DB Table per se. Having said that, you mean EXPLAIN cannot run on the VIEWS table?

Comment: I don't think I'm saying that... I'm saying that you cannot run explain on random code snippets as in `EXPLAIN SET @runningbal = 0;`.